# Trouble uploading Lambda Function in VPC from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Here's what I've done:

- I setup an Aurora Serverless MySql instance.
- Created a security group for Cloud9 which allows me to access Aurora Serverless mysql.
- Created a Lambda function which queries my db, I added the custom VPC and added the security group which lets me access Aurora Serverless (same one as Cloud9), the Lambda function works fine and can query my DB.

Before setting up Aurora Serverless, I had a RDS MySql instance which my Lambda functions could query, and had a little deploy script on my local machine which I ran to package my Lambda function's changes and uploaded them to their respective Lambda function. To setup CLI I just used this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html.

Now that I have the security group in my Lambda function, AWS CLI doesn't let me upload the Lambda function, it gets stuck during the upload process. Note: I can still upload Lamda functions using the Lambda GUI in the AWS console.

Does anyone know what I can do to upload my Lambda functions using CLI again?

[Here's a picture of where it gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0kS6.png)

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you upload your function to your own s3 bucket?

Comment: I updated the post with a picture of where it gets stuck!